# Neo4j query for complete paths

Tags: neo4j, path

I have the following structure.

```
CREATE 
(`0` :Sentence {`{text`:'This is a sentence'}}) ,
(`1` :Word {`{ text`:'This' }}) ,
(`2` :Word {`{text`:'is'}}) ,
(`3` :Sentence {`{'text'`:'Sam is a dog'}}) ,
(`0`)-[:`RELATED_TO`]->(`1`),
(`0`)-[:`RELATED_TO`]->(`2`),
(`3`)-[:`RELATED_TO`]->(`2`)
```

[schema example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6XiF.jpg)

So my question is this. I have a bunch of sentences that I have decomposed into word objects. These word objects are all unique and therefore will point to different sentences. If I perform a search for one word it's very easy to figure out all of the sentences that word is related to. How can I structure a query to figure out the same information for two words instead of one.

I would like to submit two or more words and find a path that includes all words submitted picking up all sentences of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not a very pretty approach, it basically comes down to collecting :Word nodes and using the ALL() predicate to ensure that the pattern you want holds true for all elements of the collection.

```
MATCH (w:Word) 
WHERE w.text in {myListOfWords}
WITH collect(w) as words
MATCH (s:Sentence)
WHERE ALL(word in words WHERE (s)-[:RELATED_TO]->(word))
RETURN s
```

What makes this ugly is that the planner isn't intelligent enough right now to infer that when you say `MATCH (s:Sentence) WHERE ALL(word in words ...` that the initial matches for `s` ought to come from the match from the first `w` in your `words` collection, so it starts out from all :Sentence nodes first, which is a major performance hit.

So to get around this, we have to explicitly match from the first of the `words` collection, and then use `WHERE ALL()` for the remaining.

```
MATCH (w:Word) 
WHERE w.text in {myListOfWords}
WITH w, size(()-[:RELATED_TO]->(w)) as rels
WITH w ORDER BY rels ASC
WITH collect(w) as words
WITH head(words) as head, tail(words) as words
MATCH (s)-[:RELATED_TO]->(head)
WHERE ALL(word in words WHERE (s)-[:RELATED_TO]->(word))
RETURN s
```

EDIT:

Added an optimization to order your `w` nodes by the degree of their incoming :RELATED_TO relationships (this is a degree lookup on very few nodes), as this will mean the initial match to your :Sentence nodes is the smallest possible starting set before you filter for relationships from the rest of the words.

Comment: Thanks. I'll start heading down this rabbit hole. I'm mixing python and cypher together so perhaps I might be able to decompose the above into a few smaller queries

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered an alternate approach that may work better. Compare the PROFILE on this query with the profiles for the others, see if it works better for you.

```
WITH {myListOfWords} as wordList
WITH wordList, size(wordList) as wordCnt
MATCH (s)-[:RELATED_TO]->(w:Word) 
WHERE w.text in wordList
WITH s, wordCnt, count(DISTINCT w) as cnt
WHERE wordCnt = cnt
RETURN s
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could consider using [manual indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.2/#indexing) (also called "legacy indexing") instead of using `Word` nodes and `RELATED_TO` relationships. Manual indexes support "fulltext" searches using [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/).

There are many [apoc procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_text_and_lookup_indexes) that help you with this.

Here is an example that might work for you. In this example, I assume case-insensitive comparisons are OK, you retain the `Sentence` nodes (and their `text` properties), and you want to automatically add the `text` properties of all `Sentence` nodes to a manual index.

1. If you are using neo4j 3.2+, you have to add this setting to the `neo4j.conf` file to make some expensive `apoc.index` procedures (like `apoc.index.addAllNodes`) available:

   ```
   dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
   ```
2. Execute this Cypher code to initialize a manual index named "WordIndex" with the `text` text from all existing `Sentence` nodes, and to enable automatic indexing from that point onwards:

   ```
   CALL apoc.index.addAllNodes('WordIndex', {Sentence: ['text']}, {autoUpdate: true})
   YIELD label, property, nodeCount
   RETURN *;
   ```
3. To find (case insensitively) the `Sentence` nodes containing all the words in a collection (passed via a `$words` [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/)), you'd execute a Cypher statement like the one below. The `WITH` clause builds the `lucene` query string (e.g., "foo AND bar") for you. Caveat: since lucene's special boolean terms (like "AND" and "OR") are always in uppercase, you should make sure the words you pass in are lowercased (or modify the `WITH` clause below to use the TOLOWER()` function as needed).

   ```
   WITH REDUCE(s = $words[0], x IN $words[1..] | s + ' AND ' + x) AS q
   CALL apoc.index.search('WordIndex', q) YIELD node
   RETURN node;
   ```